# What is the difference between "Often dozes off" and "alert to sounds"?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I was breeding Abras for Modest Female Abra, I got 3 of them, they stats are the same:

- Att: 4
- Def: 5
- Sp.Att: 7
- Sp.Def: 6
- Speed: 7

And they description are **ALMOST** the same:

```
Modest nature.
4/16/2012
Day-Care Couple
Egg received.
4/18/2012
Route 3
Egg hatched.
```

BUT the last line is different:

1. Alert to sounds.
2. Alert to sounds.
3. **Often dozes off.**

I am trying to level a most perfect for my tasty Abra as possible, and I Really want to understand the meaning behind this part.

I'm playing Pokemon-white [pokemon-fifth-gen](/questions/tagged/pokemon-fifth-gen)

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, it's just random.

Comment: @RavenDreamer There is some meaning behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as a Pokémon's [*characteristic*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Characteristic).  Since Diamond & Pearl, a Pokémon's status screen gives a hint as to which of its IVs is the highest in the form of an otherwise meaningless message; "Alert to sounds" means that its Speed IV is the highest and is congruent to 1 *modulo* 5, while "Often dozes off" means that its HP IV is the highest and is congruent to 1 *modulo* 5.  However, in the event that two or more IVs are tied for highest, the resulting characteristic is chosen based on the Pokémon's personality value, so it's entirely possible that the Abras all have the same IVs anyway.

Comment: Also, if the IVs *are* different, your Abra's stats are the same because at such a low level, IVs don't create a large difference (if any) in Pokémon's stats.

Comment: Can you create a more elaborate answer explaining the IV and This characteristics ?

Comment: @Michel: I don't know what else I could add that's directly relevant to the question, especially considering that most follow-up questions you might have could most likely be answered by following the link to Bulbapedia.  If you don't know what IVs are, for example, that would be a separate question and could also be answered [by a trip to Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Individual_values).